# Output flakey scenarios in Cucumber output

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm running tests in cucumber using the `--retries N` option to reattempt failed tests N times to catch some tests which are failing inconsistently. Currently the summary after running these tests in the terminal is something like this:

```
100 scenarios (2 failed, 5 flaky, 1 skipped, 98 passed)
588 steps (9 failed, 24 skipped, 555 passed)
11m45.859s

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/some_feature.feature:13 # Scenario: AC.1 Some scenario
cucumber features/some_feature.feature:54 # Scenario: AC.6 Some other scenario
```

This lets me know what's failing, however I'd like to also have a list of the flakey scenarios to help me diagnose what is failing inconsistently. Is there a way to set up Cucumber such that this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

The scenarios listed are the scenarios that fail the build (making the exit code non-zero), if you use the option "--strict" or "--strict-flaky" the flaky scenarios will also be listed in the summary ("--strict" will also list the pending and undefined scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to see Flaky scenarios in the summary.

In order to change this, someone would have to submit a pull request changing [console_issues.rb](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/32cad27b2cb59657df0b67c5e9edac80324533c3/lib/cucumber/formatter/console_issues.rb#L17), and possibly associated tests.